# I wanto call a servlet and show index.js with parameters

Tags: java, servlets, web.xml

I want when I call this URL `/`, my application calls the servlet to get parameter, and after the servlet sends parameters to `index.jsp`.

This is my `web.xml`:

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>CRUDServlet</servlet-name>
  <display-name>CRUDServlet</display-name>
  <description></description>
  <servlet-class>it.servlet.CRUDServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>CRUDServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/CRUDServlet</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
  <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

The problem is the application shows me `index.jsp` without parameters. Anyone can help  me?

Comment: change the `url-pattern` to `/` or  `*`

Comment: @Edwin I changed to / but when I go to /  , my method get in not called in serlet

Comment: Are they constants?